# Tkinter Add String To Text Object With Key

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter script, it has defined two Text Objects,
I need that when press a key from keyboard, let's say key "A"
the program writes "A" in the Text Objects I'm using, how do I detect what is the text object that I'm using?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as scrolledtext

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("900x900") 
root.minsize(height = 900, width = 900) 
root.title("Title")
label1 = tk.Label(root, text = "A:", font = ("consolas", 16), width = 60)
label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
codeinput1 = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, height = 10 , width = 60,undo = True)
codeinput1["font"] = ("fira code", "15")
codeinput1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
label2 = tk.Label(root, text = "B:", font = ("consolas", 16) , width = 60)
label2.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
codeinput2 = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, height = 10, width = 60, undo = True)
codeinput2["font"] = ("fira code", "15")
codeinput2.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
root.mainloop()
```

This is the code I have, how do I implement the following:

When using the program, let's say I'm writing in one of the two  TextObjects, when I press key "Control+F" it adds "A" to the text of the TextObjects I'm using?

Comment: This question is far too vague for anyone to answer. What is a "Text Object" in this question? A widget? A string? A custom object?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I edited it, if it is not clear, tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bind` method to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>:

```
def insert_text(event):
    codeinput2.insert(tk.END,'A')
    codeinput1.insert(tk.END,'A')
root.bind("<Control-f>",insert_text)
root.mainloop()
```

If you want to add it to the current one, you can bind the `scrolledtext.ScrolledText` to Left Button and then bind it:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as scrolledtext

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("900x900") 
root.minsize(height = 900, width = 900) 
root.title("Title")

label1 = tk.Label(root, text = "A:", font = ("consolas", 16), width = 60)
label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

codeinput1 = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, height = 10 , width = 60,undo = True)
codeinput1["font"] = ("fira code", "15")
codeinput1.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",lambda event: codeinput1.bind("<Control-f>",insert_text))
codeinput1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text = "B:", font = ("consolas", 16) , width = 60)
label2.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

codeinput2 = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, height = 10, width = 60, undo = True)
codeinput2["font"] = ("fira code", "15")
codeinput2.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",lambda event: codeinput2.bind("<Control-f>",insert_text))
codeinput2.grid(row = 3, column = 0)

def insert_text(event):
    event.widget.insert(tk.END,'A')

root.mainloop()
```

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html?highlight=bind#bindings-and-events) of `bind`.

See [virtual events](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/event.html) for `tkinter`